# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, string, rest, dictionary, http-request

In the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import json

APPLICATION_NAME = 'cc9226315643df89-36bf02429075329d0ba36748360d050c'

HEADERS1 = json.dumps(dict(Destination = u"/api/af/latest/applications/%s/rulesets" % (APPLICATION_NAME)))
print "Headers1 is %s" % (HEADERS1)
HEADERS2 = {'Destination': '/api/af/latest/applications/%s/rulesets' % (APPLICATION_NAME)}
print "Headers2 is %s" % (HEADERS2)
```

I get the following output:

```
Headers1 is {"Destination": "/api/af/latest/applications/cc9226315643df89-36bf02429075329d0ba36748360d050c/rulesets"}
Headers2 is {'Destination': '/api/af/latest/applications/cc9226315643df89-36bf02429075329d0ba36748360d050c/rulesets'}
```

but when I try to use either HEADER1 or HEADER2 in a REST call using requests(), I get very different results:

```
SERVER_URL = 'http://1.1.33.109:8087%s' % (APP_PATH)
REQ_DATA = None
print "Headers are: ", HEADERS
print "SERVER_URL is: ", SERVER_URL
print "Request Data is:", REQ_DATA
print ""

RESPONSE = requests.request(
    'MOVE', 
    SERVER_URL, 
    auth = ('admin', 'admin'), 
    verify = False, 
    data = REQ_DATA,
    headers = HEADERS1 )     #<-- If I use HEADER1 it breaks, if I use HEADER2 it works
print "Move Ruleset back to the Application RESULT: %s\n" % (RESPONSE)
```

I get the following with HEADER1:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./myrest.py", line 234, in <module>
     headers = HEADERS1 )
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 324, in request
     prep = req.prepare()
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 223, in prepare
     p.prepare_headers(self.headers)
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 340, in prepare_headers
     headers = dict((name.encode('ascii'), value) for name, value in headers.items())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

If I use HEADER2 it executes cleanly:

> Move Ruleset back to the Application RESULT: Response [200]

Can anyone explain what the differences are?

Comment: What makes you think a JSON-encoded string would be acceptable as a headers dictionary for a HTTP request?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You are passing in a *string*; `headers` can't *ever* be a JSON encoded string, it is always a Python dictionary.

The `print` results are deceptive; JSON encoded objects look a lot like Python dictionary representations but they are **far** from the same thing.

The [`requests` API](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) clearly states that `headers` must be a dictionary:

> - `headers` – (optional) Dictionary of HTTP Headers to send with the `Request`.

JSON data is something you'd send as content to another server, not something you'd use to communicate with a Python API.

Comment: I see - I checked with type() and saw the differences:                 Headers1 is {"Destination": "/api/af/latest/applications/cc9226315643df89-36bf02429075329d0ba36748360d050c/rulesets"}
Headers1 is of type:  <type 'str'>
Headers2 is {'Destination': '/api/af/latest/applications/cc9226315643df89-36bf02429075329d0ba36748360d050c/rulesets'}
Headers2 is of type:  <type 'dict'>

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue and I needed to make the header with a content type and pass in a data element as json.

```
import requests
import json

headerInfo = {'content-type': 'application/json' }
payload = {'text': 'okay!!!', 'auth_token': 'aasdasdasdasd'}
jLoad = json.dumps(payload)

r = requests.post('http://example.com:3030/widgets/init', headers=headerInfo, data=jLoad)
print r.text
print r.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can pass  {

```
  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
}
```

it worked